Why are mounting hole locations for many Arduino and Nucleo boards so strange?
The mounting hole positions are so simple in case of the Raspberry Pi 4 for example:

But on the Arduino Mega, you see this odd constellation:

And on the Arduino Uno R3, they are placed very arbitrarily:

Also on an STM32 Nucleo board:

What is the reason for these seemingly "random" placements of mounting points in the latter 3 cases? Is there any specific consideration behind them like: better airflow in some casing assemblies, better mechanical stress or vibration resistance, etc?
(I noticed that usually at least 2 holes have some kind of clearance radius for screw heads or washers/nuts, but the third/further holes do not. I wonder, should the former 2 of them be fixed with threaded brass spacers/screws and the further ones only with some plastic pins?)

wdym by arbitrary? The holes are placed along the outer edge of the boards, but the spacing is based around imperial measurements, which is more or less common on circuit boards for legacy reasons (as all other uses of imperial measurements tbh)
Are there any special considerations about them? Yes probably, but unless you ask the original designers, the answers will be speculations only.

My definition of arbitrary here: If I connect the drill points to get a (mostly convex) polygon, it is an arbitrary polygon. Or e.g. if it is triangle (in case of the Nucleo64 board), none of its sides are parallel to the edges of the PCB.
Actually I hope that there could be insiders here who have asked this question at a trade show or were educated about them, and might know an answer.
If I designed these things I am sure the first things I would have placed on the PCB are the mounting points, in some basic rectangle or trapezoid shape, paralel to edges of the board.

Anyway, I also have a slight intuition that the holes might be more related to the connector pin array positions than their relevance as mounting points. Notice how the holes on the Arduino Mega and STM32 Nucleo boards are in line with the pins next to them. They could be positioning guides (?) similarly to the holes purpose are in case of these JTAG connectors: https://www.tag-connect.com

But isn't the expectation that a polygon defined by the NPTHs should create some "understandable" polygon, in itself arbitrary? I mean, I'd also always try to involve some pretty symmetry in my PCB designs, and mounting holes would be part of that - but again, as long as we don't know the design process that led up to the way it is, it would mostly be speculations. It is also quite possible that it just "became" that way. Some early prototypes had that design - someone else made some jig for that, and suddenly an interface was born. 1/x

And the different boards from different manufacturers likely also have different decisions as the basis for their hole placement, so even if one could deduce some rules from one of them, it would really not generalize across to the others

The mounting holes should be the minimum number of supports to prevent board flex from external forces such as vertical headers, while horizontal jacks are less affected.  Each board has different headers which are major influences.  I can't comment on the resulting strains but there is some logic to this.
